# How should I set-up my solution when using ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When using ASP.net webforms my usual solution would have following type of setup -

1. MyCompany.MyProject.Presentation.MyWebFormsApp (asp.net web forms )
2. MyCompany.MyProject.Service.MyServieLayer (WCF/Web Service)
3. MyCompany.MyProject.Business.MyBusinessLogicLayer (class project)
4. MyCompany.MyProject.DataAccess.MyDALayer (class project/Linq2SQL/NHibernate == DataModel)
5. MyCompany.MyProject.DataTransferObjects.MyDomainLayer (class project)
6. {whole bunch of test projects}

When using ASP.net MVC, I have used this kind of solution breakdown -

1. MyCompany.MyProject.Presentation.MyMVCApp (ASP.net MVC project)
2. MyCompany.MyProject.DataAccess.MyDALayer (class project/Linq2SQL/NHibernate == DataModel)
3. {whole bunch of test projects}

**Question**
In an AP.net MVC setup how do I wire up my DomainObjects/DTO/POCO and the WCF/Web Service layers?? Do I lose out on any features if I want to keep the solution like I used for WebForms??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC project should only differs in Web Project, everything else should remain the same. In web project the regular page you have in Web forms application will now split into controller and view.

Comment: Do I lose out any of straight out of the box features??